# Taking the first Char of a String until the String is empty ""

Tags: java, string, char, substring

I am currently working on a task and I have a question about the Substring method.
For the task I need to get the first Char of a String and delete the first Char after I used it.

The Strings are names and at the end I only want to have "" an empty String left.

My approach:

```
        String name = "Paul";
        char chr = name.charAt(0);
        String newName = name.substring(1);
```

My questions: When I am at the last char "l" and use my substring do I get "" or an error?

Comment: Sorry, I have to point out that you will spend less time solving the problem by run code in an IDE than ask question here. For the question, you will get an error, since idk implements substring ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My questions: When I am at the last char "l" and use my substring do I
> get "" or an error?

You will get a blank string. It is also mentioned in the following lines of [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)):

> **Throws:**
>
> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

When you have only `l` left in the string, its length will be `1` which is perfectly acceptable as the `beginIndex`. You can also verify it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("l".substring(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But is this just better code or is it necessary? Because I don't get an error when I use my method and the function is a recursive call until the String is empty or equals "".

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that is error free, do the following.

```
String name = "Paul"; 
int nameLength = name.length();
for (int i = 0; i < nameLength; i++){ 
    char chr = name.charAt(0);
    if (i != nameLength - 1){
        String newName = name.substring(1);
        name = newName;
    } else {
        name = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. But how is this different at the last case? When I am at only one letter and do name.substring(1) i get the same error and not "" right?

Comment: @Yohnson changed to get rid of error.